# Auto-compute for the total product of two columns -- inolves dynamic table rows

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-selectors

Consider the following HTML tables:

```
<table id="myTable1">
    <tr id="TR1">
        <td><input type="text" id="quantity1" name="quantity1" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="weight1" name="weight1" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table id="myTable2">
   <td><input type="text" id="total_weight" name="total_weight" /></td>
</table>
```

What I'm trying to accomplish here is that I need to update the **product** value for the **total_weight** field based on the values type in the **quantity** and **weight** fields every time **keyup()** is triggered on these last two mentioned  fields. So basically this would be something like **total_weight += (quantity * weight)**.

Now it is expected that **myTable1** will contain several rows since as the title states, **myTable1** is a dynamic table such that the user can add/delete rows on a press of a button --- a feature I have already implemented.

I have the following code that computes for the **total_weight** with the exclusion of the **quantity column**. I just need figure out how to plug in quantity to multiply with weight in there:

```
// Auto-compute (total weight)
$('#myTable1 input[id^=\'weight\']').live('keyup',function() {
    var total_weight = 0;

    $('#myTable1 input[id^=\'weight\']').each(function(index, value) {
        total_weight += Number($(this).val());

        $('#myTable2 #total_weight').val(total_weight);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close with your code.  Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wG47W/2/) using this js...

```
// Auto-compute (total weight)
$('#myTable1 input[id^=weight], #myTable1 input[id^=quantity]').live('keyup',function() {
    var total_weight = 0;

    $('#myTable1 input[id^=weight]').each(function(index, value) {
        var n = $(this).attr('id').substr(6);
        total_weight += (Number($(this).val()) * Number($('#quantity' + n).val()));
        $('#myTable2 #total_weight').val(total_weight);
    });
});
```